# Airflow DAG tasks parallelism on different worker nodes

Tags: python, airflow-scheduler, airflow

I have an Airflow cluster made of 3 worker nodes with CeleryExecutor and RabbitMQ for communication.
My DAGs usually consist of tasks that download files, unzip them, upload them to hadoop, etc. So they depend on each other and must run on single machine/node.

When airflow schedules these tasks of a single DAG, **on different nodes**, I end up with errors because these tasks are scheduled on different machines but I need all tasks within a DAG to be scheduled on a single machine.

I tried setting dag_concurrency = 1 and max_active_runs_per_dag = 1 both on airflow.cfg and when initializing the dag, DAG(concurrency = 1, max_active_runs = 1) with no success.

Rest of my airflow.cfg:

```
parallelism = 32
dag_concurrency = 1
worker_concurrency = 16
max_active_runs_per_dag = 16
```

As far as I understand, setting dag_concurrency to 1 should do the trick but what am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CeleryExecutor` supports multiple `queues`, you could define a specific queue for each operator (is an attribute of `BaseOperator`) and then subscribe each worker to that specific queue. Note that workers can listen to one or multiple queues.

From the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/celery.html#queues):

> Workers can listen to one or multiple queues of tasks. When a worker
> is started (using the command airflow celery worker), a set of
> comma-delimited queue names can be specified (e.g. airflow celery
> worker -q spark). This worker will then only pick up tasks wired to
> the specified queue(s)

This is an example DAG:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago


default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': days_ago(1),
}
dag = DAG('dist_example',
          schedule_interval='@once',
          catchup=False,
          default_args=default_args
          )
get_hostname = 'echo $(hostname)'

t1 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_for_q1',
    bash_command=get_hostname,
    queue='queue_1',
    dag=dag
)
t2 = BashOperator(
    task_id='task_for_q2',
    bash_command=get_hostname,
    queue='queue_2',
    dag=dag
)
t1 >> t2
```

worker_1:
`airflow celery worker -q default,queue_1`

worker_2:
`airflow celery worker -q default,queue_2`

By listening to both your specific queue and `default` (defined by `default_queue` config key) you won't affect the standard multi-workers behavior for any other tasks.

I hope that works for you!

Comment: Thank you for response. I will try this and let others know, too. How about dag_concurrency though? Am I misinterpreting what it is supposed to do or what?

Comment: Yeap I think so. [Quote](https://www.astronomer.io/guides/airflow-scaling-workers):  ..."`dag_concurrency` determines how many task instances the Airflow Scheduler is able to schedule at once per DAG. Think of this as "maximum tasks that can be scheduled at once, per DAG.""... If you have multiple workers, those tasks will be distributed among them.

Comment: Thanks again, your solution works and I am using it now. However I still don't understand why simply setting dag_concurrency = 1 did not do the work.

Comment: Glad to hear that it worked! Regarding `dag_concurrency`, the Airflow [FAQ](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/faq.html) refers to it as ..." defines how many running task instances a DAG is allowed to have, beyond which point things get queued"... You can also monitor how many task are being executed using Celery Flower, when running only that particular DAG, you should see that the max amount of tasks being exeuted will be equal to the concurrency setting, the others remain queued.