# Running airflow DAG/tasks on different hosts

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

We currently have a bunch of independent jobs running on different servers & being scheduled with crontab. The goal would be to have a single view of all the jobs across the servers and whether they've run successfully etc.

Airflow is one of the tools we are considering using to achieve this. But our servers are configured very differently. Is it possible to set up airflow so that DAG1 (and the airflow scheduler & webserver) runs on server1 and DAG2 runs on server2 without RabbitMQ.

Essentially I'd like to achieve something like the first answer given here (or just at a DAG level): [Airflow DAG tasks parallelism on different worker nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67576517/airflow-dag-tasks-parallelism-on-different-worker-nodes)
in the quickest & simplest way possible!

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can checkout [Running Apache-Airflow with Celery Executor in Docker](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html).

To use celery, you can instantiate a redis node as a pod and proceed with managing tasks across multiple hosts.

The link above will also give you a starter docker-compose yaml to help you get started quickly with Apache Airflow on celery executor.

> Is it possible to set up airflow so that DAG1 (and the airflow
> scheduler & webserver) runs on server1 and DAG2 runs on server2
> without RabbitMQ.

Airflow by default will try to use multiple hosts on Celery Executor and the division will always be on task level and not on DAG level.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186335/assigning-tasks-to-specific-machines-with-airflow) might help you with spawning specific tasks on a specific worker node.

Comment: There will always be one webserver showing you all the DAGs in the system. Same with the scheduler. To spawn multiple scheduler threads you can checkout the Airflow configuration.